# Issue with removing newline character from unicode string in python

Tags: python, unicode, newline, unicode-string

I have a piece of Unicode text. I wanted to remove all newline characters from the text before printing the output. My code looks something like this:

```
input_string = u'\u3010JK\u3011\u9032\u5b66\u306b\u56f0\u3063\u305f\uff2a\uff2b\u304c\u5148\u751f\u306b\u52a9\u3051\u3066\u3082\u3089\u3046\u305f\u3081\u306b\uff33\uff25\uff38\uff01.mov'
output_string = ' '.join(input_string.splitlines())
print output_string
```

I was hoping the library method to take care of all the dirty newline uncicode character cases. But, it looks like this method doesn't remove newline character from the given input. Please suggest a solution to remove newline character from the given input.

Comment: Where do we have newline characters here?

Comment: The output string prints newline characters. So i am not able to get why this behavior.

Comment: I see no newline chars in the string itself. However, print adds one at the end, maybe you confused it with chars?

Answer (score 5):

According to my Python, your string contains no characters of category `Cc` (control character):

```
>>> unicodedata.category(u'\n') in map(unicodedata.category, input_string)
False
```

so there is no newline in this string. `unicodedata.name` confirms this:

```
>>> for c in s: print unicodedata.name(c)
... 
LEFT BLACK LENTICULAR BRACKET
LATIN CAPITAL LETTER J
LATIN CAPITAL LETTER K
RIGHT BLACK LENTICULAR BRACKET
CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-9032
CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-5B66
HIRAGANA LETTER NI
CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-56F0
HIRAGANA LETTER SMALL TU
HIRAGANA LETTER TA
FULLWIDTH LATIN CAPITAL LETTER J
FULLWIDTH LATIN CAPITAL LETTER K
HIRAGANA LETTER GA
CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-5148
CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-751F
HIRAGANA LETTER NI
CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-52A9
HIRAGANA LETTER KE
HIRAGANA LETTER TE
HIRAGANA LETTER MO
HIRAGANA LETTER RA
HIRAGANA LETTER U
HIRAGANA LETTER TA
HIRAGANA LETTER ME
HIRAGANA LETTER NI
FULLWIDTH LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
FULLWIDTH LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
FULLWIDTH LATIN CAPITAL LETTER X
FULLWIDTH EXCLAMATION MARK
FULL STOP
LATIN SMALL LETTER M
LATIN SMALL LETTER O
LATIN SMALL LETTER V
```

Comment: It turns out that there seems to be some problem with rendering this text in Unix. 

    for i,v in enumerate(output_string): print i,v

In output for the above line, index 13th value prints a newline in Unix console, whereas, a Chinese character is printed in windows.

Comment: @Vamsi: then you should set your terminal to UTF-8. Consult your manual on how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

There are no newlines or anything like newlines in this string. It has 33 characters and all of them are printable characters, not formatting.

Maybe you're confused by the fact that the `print` statement adds a newline to the end vs. the behavior of `sys.stdout.write`?

Comment: It turns out that there seems to be some problem with rendering this text in Unix. 

    for i,v in enumerate(output_string): print i,v

In output for the above line, index 13th value prints a newline in Unix console, whereas, a Chinese character is printed in windows.